# why Object.to string is returning true for List type

Tags: java, list, object, generics

I just wrote these two lines out of curiosity :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Object obj = new ArrayList<String>().add("Some text");
    System.out.println("output : " + obj.toString());
}
```

Since Object class is super class of everything, this code compiles properly. But when I run this, it give me output as :

```
output : true
```

What could be the possible reasons for that?

Comment: `ArrayList`'s `add()` returns a `boolean`, and that's what you store in `obj`.

Comment: my bad.... I didn't notice add :|

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Object you are printing is returned by `new ArrayList<String>().add("Some text")`. `add()` returns a `boolean` (in fact for `ArrayList`, it always returns `true`), which, when assigned to an `Object` variable, is auto-boxed to a `Boolean`.

```
/**
 * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
 *
 * @param e element to be appended to this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```